# Do i need to "new" a array in order to do memset later? in c++

Tags: c++, scope, new-operator

For example

I have char `str[1024];`

And I will do `memset(str,0,1024);` later

Is this okay,?
OR 
i need to do this:

```
char* str = new char[1024];
```

thanks.

Comment: Depends on if you want the array to outlive the scope it's in.

Comment: as a note, you can use `char* str = new char[1024]();` to value-initialize the array to 0 automatically

Comment: @lezebulon : Not just can, _should_.

Comment: `char str[1024] = ""` is a better method of doing it.  Always initialize your variables to something.

Comment: @CrazyEddie : That's wrong for two reasons. 1) `char str[1024]` and `char* str` have very different semantics. 2) `()` introduces value-initialization, and value-initialization _is_ initialization (obviously), and it has defined semantics according to the standard, and in this case, _clearer_ semantics (assuming one knows the rules).

Comment: @ildjarn - Do you know what the line of code I showed does?  It rather seems maybe you do not as that's the only sense I can make of you saying it's wrong due to anything you've said.  You should though.

Comment: @CrazyEddie : Do _you_? Do you know the object lifetime guarantees associated with that vs. what lezebulon posted? If you have a point, it's certainly not clear.

Comment: I think you two completely misunderstood each other.

Comment: @ildjarn - And what, pray tell, does anything lezebulon said have to do with what I said to the OP?? O_o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @HostileFork already pointed out, you probably want `std::string` here. If whatever you're doing isn't particularly string-like, then you may want `std::vector<char> str(1024);` instead.

Either way, you it's quite certain you don't want `new char[1024]` (a leftover from an early era of C++ that probably wouldn't be in the language at all if other facilities were present) and *probably* don't want `char str[1024];` either, though there's at least *some* possibility that this one isn't an egregious mistake.

Comment: I'm sure that in every case, `new char[1024]` would be in the language, if only for reasons of orthogonality.  Without the history of C, it would probably have usable semantics; as it is, I've never found a use for it.  (And `char str[N];` is useful when interfacing with legacy functions, like `strftime()`.)

Comment: Why it's better to use std::vector<char> str(1024); instead of char str[1024]; thanks.  @Jerry Coffin

Comment: It has several advantages; the ones you care about will vary. Sometimes you care that it can be resized at need. Others that you can find the current size easily. Others that you can pass it as a parameter without it decaying into a pointer. etc.

Answer (score 5):

Both allocate space so either will work with memset. The difference between the two is in where the space is allocated.

```
char str[1024];
```

Allocates the string on the stack and will go away once it's out of scope.

```
char* str = new char[1024];
```

Allocates the string on the heap and will be around forever until you delete[] it.

Answer (score 1):

Direct answer: no.

Better answer: don't use memset in C++.  Honestly you probably shouldn't be using memset in C either, at least not for all the things it's commonly used for.  In C++ especially though, setting all bytes to 0 is not always the right way to "blank" a variable....even an array.  This is technically true of C as well but memset has decades of abuse behind it...nobody's going to make an implementation that behaves differently.

Comment: It's an array of `char`, setting all bytes to 0 is probably the right way to "blank" it.

Comment: @SethCarnegie - because we should all code in a manner that *probably* does what we expect.

Comment: Obviously I said probably because I don't know his situation, not because we don't know what our situations are.

Answer (score 0):

Storing `str`ings in character arrays and setting them with `memset` is not idiomatic C++.

*(Note: I sure do use the word [idiomatic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiom) a lot.)*

Speaking of what a broken record I am, I plead with you to read this short paper by Bjarne Stroustrup:

[Learning Standard C++ As a New Language](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/new_learning.pdf)

Don't be (too) afraid to show StackOverflow veterans more context of the question you're dealing with, because you might be surprised at the cool re-imaginations and improvements on your code they suggest...

To make this more of an *answer*, your declaration should probably read:

```
std::string str;
```

You don't have to manage the size, and you may return it by value to a calling scope (or not).